# Batch processing and breaking up an image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to segment each charm item in this collective image.

The shapes are irregular and inconsistent:

https://i.imgur.com/sf8nOau.jpg

I have another image where there is some consistency with the top row of items, but ideally I'd be able to process and brake up all items in one go:

http://i.imgur.com/WiiYBay.jpg

I have no experience with opencv so I'm just looking for best possible tool or approach to take. I've read about background subtraction as well as color clustering, but I'm not sure about those either.

Any ideas on how to best approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

im=cv2.imread('so1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
res = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)
res = cv2.erode(res,kernel,iterations = 1)
res = cv2.dilate(res,kernel,iterations = 1)

cv2.imshow('thresh',res)
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(res.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('image',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Output

[image]

Now having the contours you can crop them out

## Code Update

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

im=cv2.imread('so.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
res = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)
res = cv2.erode(res,kernel,iterations = 1)
res = cv2.dilate(res,kernel,iterations = 8)

cv2.imshow('thresh',res)
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(res.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
count=0

for cnt in contours:
    blank=np.zeros(im.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    epsilon = 0.001*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(blank,approx,(255, 255, 255))
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(im, blank)
    cv2.imwrite('results_so/im'+str(count)+'.jpg',masked_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    count+=1
cv2.imshow('image',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## results

### good one

[image]

### bad one

[image]

Some small noises are also detected as objects you can eliminate those by only taking contours whose area is greater than a certain value .

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply and sample code! Can I ask how you got the cv2.findContours to find each item perfectly (with the bounding rectangle)?

When I run the script, cv2.findContours is way too aggressive and is identifying a lot of noise. I read that it's best to use a binary image (.png) instead of a .jpg, but that didn't help.

Here is the result when I run it:

Comment: Woops, forgot to link it. Here is the result when I run it: http://i.imgur.com/zahkK9G.png

Comment: Binary image means a threaholded image . Things you should try blur the image a bit , change the parameters a bit , add threahold value so only contours greater than a certain area is deteced in your case to remove the small rectangles . I just used the boundingBox to get you a brief idea , you get the perimeter of the contour and create a mask to get the exact object . Most of the things you need http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html#table-of-content-contours take a look here .

Comment: Actually 1 downsized your image . . In your case you can dialate the thresholed image . http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation

Comment: Thanks again for the advice. I've tried both median and Gaussian blur to cut noise during pre-processing, and added "max_index" argument to select for largest respective contour. Played with all sorts of parameters. But I still get a lot of smaller bounding boxes around smaller contours, you can see here: 

https://dpaste.de/Pi6i

Any other ideas?

Comment: you can add more iteration to dilation 
    res = cv2.dilate(res,kernel,iterations = 2)

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, I really appreciate it. Increasing iterations helped some, but the best change was adding cv2.morphologyEx function as it filled in the disconnected white regions. See here: https://dpaste.de/Hc7j#L7,13


Only two problems now, how do I discard the border contour? It get returned as a contour by cv2.findContours and ignores the rest of the blobs. When I manually crop the border, it finds the rest of items properly.

Also how do I extract all of the contours (items) found? You can see I tried with cv2.imwrite on line 25, but only one gets exported.

Thanks

Comment: only saving the roi wont do the job in your case in some cases the bounding rectangle will contain some part from other objects . These steps might help you . . Detect Bounding Box -> Detect polygon of the contour -> Create a blank image of the size of bounding box -> Use the polygon as a mask -> add the created blank image with the original roi , using the contour polygon as a mask . . http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-approximation

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I was actually able to extract the contour of each image using the roi, but as you described there is overlap with the bounding rectangle.

Your idea seems reasonable but is outside my ability level with opencv right now, it took a while to even find cv2.morphologyEx function to fix my disjointed white blobs. 

Is there any chance you can find it in your heart of hearts to throw me some sample code of how your idea would play out?

Thanks in any event, you're a legend.

Comment: Wow! That's very neat, I tried playing with parameters (increase epsilon) and filtering by area using cv2.contourArea function, but using the mask is inconsistent. It will cut through areas of a blob and I can't fix it. See here: http://i.imgur.com/9tD33c4.png

Also I can't fill the black background with another color (white). Is it even possible or does it need to be b/w for extraction?

Perhaps, it's best to just put up with overlap. My last problem is that I when I read in each file from a folder, the resulting files that are extracted overwrite each other after each loop. See here:

Comment: I don't have your images right now . show me the output .